# $\underbrace{\sum_{x = 1}^{r} \ldots \sum_{x = 1}^{r}}_{\text{n times}} x = ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f(n,r) = \sum_{x = 1}^{r} f(n - 1,x)$ with $f(0,x) = x$.

We get

$$f(n,r) = \underbrace{\sum_{x_{n-1} = 1}^{x_n = r} \ldots \sum_{x = 1}^{x_1}}_{\text{n times}}x\text{ .}$$

This sum popped up when I was trying to find a formula for the numbers in Pascal's triangle and I have no idea about solving it.

I tried figuring out the first sum $f(1,r)$ and it is the triangular number $\frac{r(r + 1)}{2}$ and tried figuring out the second sum $f(2,r)$ in terms of the first by naming $\frac{r(r + 1)}{2}$ as $F(r)$:

$
\begin{eqnarray}
f(2,r)&=& \sum_{x_1 = 1}^{r}\color{blue}{\sum_{x = 1}^{x_1} x} \\
&=& \sum_{x_1 = 1}^{r} \color{blue}{\frac{x_1(x_1+1)}{2}} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_1 = 1}^{r} x_1(x_1 + 1) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(2 + 6 + 12 + \ldots + r(r + 1)) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}((2 + (2 + 2 \cdot 2) + \ldots + r(r + 1)) \\
&=& \color{green}{\frac{1}{2}}(\color{green}{2}(1) + \color{green}{2}(1 + 2) + \ldots + \color{green}{2}(1 + 2 + \ldots + r)) \\
&=& (1) + (1 + 2) + \ldots + (1 + 2 + \ldots + r) \\
&=& \color{blue}{r(1 + 2 + \ldots + r)}\color{purple}{- ((r-0) + (r - 1) + \ldots + 2)} \\
&=& \color{blue}{\frac{r^2(r + 1)}{2}} \color{purple}{- r(r - 1) + \frac{(r - 1)(r - 2)}{2}} \\
&=& rF(r) - 2F(r - 1) + F(r - 2) \\
&=& rF(r) - 2(F(r) - r) + (F(r) - (r + (r - 1))) \\
&=& rF(r) - 2F(r) + 2r + F(r) - 2r + 1 \\
&=& rF(r) - F(r) + 1 \\
&=& (r - 1)F(r) + 1 \end{eqnarray}
$

After getting a formula for $f(n,r)$ in terms of $f(1,r)$, you swap $r$ for $x$ to get a sum $f(n + 1,x)$ that runs from $1$ to $r$, then you find a formula for $f(n + 1,r)$ in terms of $f(1,r)$ and swap to get $f(n+2,r)$ and so on, at least this was how the sum was defined in the context of my work on the formula for the numbers of Pascal's triangle.

For example:

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(1,r) &=& \sum_{x = 1}^{r} x \\
&=& \frac{r(r + 1)}{2} \\
&=& F(r) \\ \\
f(2,r) &=& \sum_{x = 1}^{r} F(x) \\
&=& (r - 1)F(r) + 1 \\
&=& G\circ F(r) \\ \\
f(3,r) &=& \sum_{x = 1}^{r} G\circ F(x) \end{eqnarray}$$

I don't know if their exists such a formula in terms of the first sum for any number of sums we take, I stopped to see if there is any easier way to solve it.

Comment: When you say  $\sum\limits_{x = 1}^{r} (1 + 2 + \ldots + r) = \frac{r^2(r + 1)}{2} - (r + (r - 1) + (r - 2) + \ldots + 2)$ why did you not say $\sum\limits_{x = 1}^{r} (1 + 2 + \ldots + r) = \frac{r^2(r + 1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: I think I made a mistake because I should have plugged in $1 + 2 + \ldots + r$ for $\frac{r(r + 1)}{2}$ and then change the $r$ to an $x$ to avoid confusion: $\sum_{x = 1}^{r} \frac{x(x + 1)}{2}$.

Comment: There's the obvious issue of you calling with the same name $x$ several different dummy variables *and* a constant.

Comment: So how should I write it?

Comment: I don't know. I can't read that.

Comment: Perhaps $f(n,r) = \underbrace{\sum_{s = 1}^{r} \sum_{t = 1}^{s} \ldots \sum_{x = 1}^{w}}_{\text{n times}} x$ if that is what you intended.  It is a binomial coefficient

Comment: But this doesn't specify that $s$ and $w$ are equal to $r$. The thing is you sum numbers up to $r$ then you get a formula and plug in $x$ for $r$ to get the second sum and you find a formula for it and so on.

Comment: I fixed it, I showed the steps for calculating the second sum. Maybe you would understand what I mean.

Comment: I think I understand what you intended to ask. Try defining your function recursively. So $f(0,x)=x$ and $f(n,x)=\sum_{k=1}^x f(n-1,k)$

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't think anyone has an answer though...

Comment: @mohamedshawky No one "has an answer" because you haven't properly asked your question. You should edit your question so that it properly reflects what you intended. As of now, the answer given by VIVID answers the question that you asked.

Comment: I apologize, I just didn't know how to define it exactly, my bad. Thanks.

Comment: The way Henry specified it is what you want.

Comment: This is closely related to [Finding sum : ${\mathop{\sum\sum\sum\sum}_{0\le i\lt j\lt k\lt l\le n }} \,1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2342139)

Comment: Yes, but this is a lot more complicated.

Comment: Check out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2495962/sum-of-simplicial-polytopic-numbers?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a somewhat combinatorial approach to this problem that uses hockey-stick identity.
Note that $f(0,x)=\binom{x}{1}$. We have that
$$f(1,r)=\sum_{x=1}^r \binom{x}{1}$$
Using hockey-stick identity, this is
$$f(1,r)=\binom{r+1}{2}$$
We are motivated to proceed by induction. We hypothesize that $f(n,r)=\binom{r+n}{n+1}$. We have already established our base case. To prove our inductive step, we want to prove, given $f(n-1,r)=\binom{r+n-1}{n}$, that
$$f(n,r)=\binom{r+n}{n+1}$$
Since we have the recursion
$$f(n,r)=\sum_{x=1}^r \binom{x+n-1}{n}$$
By hockey-stick identity, this simplifies to
$$\binom{r+n}{n+1}$$
Hence, our proof by induction is complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't think it was that simple.

Comment: (+1) This is the same idea as used in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2342151) to a related question.